# How do I use a different .env file when starting a webServer in Playwright?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, playwright, dotenv

I am introducing Playwright into my project. My current project structure has a separate backend and frontend in a single repo, and Playwright is installed in the frontend part of the project.

```
├ .git
├ frontend/                  
│    ├ ...          
│    ├ playwright.config.ts           
│    ├ .env                  
│    └ package.json 
└ backend/          
     ├ ...          
     ├ server.js    
     ├ .env         
     └ package.json
```

When I run `npx playwright test` from within `/frontend`, I want both my frontend and backend services to start up.

```
// playwright.config.ts
webServer: [
  {
    // start frontend
    command: "npm run start",
    port: 3000,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
  {
    // start backend
    command: "cd ../backend && node server",
    port: 3001,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
]
```

However, the environment variables that are specified in `/frontend/.env` are the ones that are being passed to the backend, so the backend has an incomplete or faulty configuration when it attempts to start. I have tried using the `env` property and specifying the path to the backend `.env` file in `dotenv.config()`, but then it overrides the frontend environment variables, giving me the same but opposite problem.

How can I get `/backend/.env` to be used by the backend process, and `/frontend/.env` to be used by the frontend process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force `dotenv` to read each of the `.env` files and then cache the value of `process.env`. Then I could pass the environment variables to each webserver with the `env` property. Since I want `/frontend/.env` to be loaded into `process.env`, I load `/backend/.env` first.

`override: true` is required for the second call of `dotenv.config()` if you have conflicting environment variables, such as `PORT`. By default, `dotenv` will not set environment variables that already exist, so any variables with the same name will not get set.

```js
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from "@playwright/test";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({ path: "../backend/.env", override: true });
const backendEnv = { ...process.env } as { [key: string]: string };
dotenv.config({ override: true });
const frontendEnv = { ...process.env } as { [key: string]: string };

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  // omitted config above...
  webServer: [
    {
      command: "npm run start",
      port: 3000,
      reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
      env: frontendEnv,
    },
    {
      command: "cd ../backend && node server",
      port: 3001,
      reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
      env: backendEnv,
    },
  ],
}
```